# Perl Archive::Tar how to exclude root directory

Tags: perl

I need to extract `.tgz` file ( contains directory tree/files) in `d:\work` directory , make some changes and repack it again. 
The extracted folder will be like `D:\work\123a\...` ( so th `.tgz` contains folder `123a` and many *subfolders\files*.
Now I tried to use `Archive::Tar` and pack recursively, but the problem is "work" folder is also compressed.  - So it will be `\work\123a\...`
How to exclude this "work" folder (cwd or root dir).
Any help is appreciated. 
my code:

```
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;        
    $tar->read("$tgzfiles[0]");
    $tar->extract();
    (my $tgzfolder = $tgzfiles[0]) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;       

       # Here I make some changes in content{.....}

    our $arc = Archive::Tar->new();
    find( \&archiveit, "d:/work/$tgzfolder" );
    $arc->write("$tgzfiles[0]", 9);


    sub archiveit {
             $arc->add_files( $File::Find::name );

    }
```

Comment: Please lay out your code properly so that it is readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. The initial `test.tgz` is located in the home folder.

I used [chdir](http://p3rl.org/chdir) to switch to the working directory, but then I needed to provide the `no_chdir` option to the `wanted` function to prevent changing the directory into the subdirectories.

Also, I guess the $tgzfolder should be the path to the extracted files, so it should be extracted from the archive contents, not from its name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find;

my @tgzfiles = "$ENV{HOME}/test.tgz";

chdir 'd:/work';

my $tar = 'Archive::Tar'->new;
$tar->read($tgzfiles[0]);
$tar->extract;

# Modify the contents.

my $tgzfolder = ($tar->list_files)[0];

my $arc = 'Archive::Tar'->new;
find({wanted   => sub { $arc->add_files($File::Find::name) },
      no_chdir => 1},
     $tgzfolder );
$arc->write($tgzfiles[0], 9);
```

Comment: hi, it is already there, but still same, maybe be because of this find it include work directory too:$arc->add_files( $File::Find::name );

Comment: What's the content of @tgzfiles?

Comment: Check the update. I had to guess a lot, next time please try to provide all the details.

Comment: Thank you, yes it is working, thanks for the find wanted.., sorry this is my first post and I tried to copy entire code, but somehow it was taking only this much.